# Why are valence band and conduction bands parabolic in semiconductor physics?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, laser

I was learning about semiconductor lasers where direct and indirect band gap plays a major role in their working, then this doubt struck my mind: Why are valence band and conduction bands parabolic in semiconductor physics?

Comment: Any dispersion relation is parabolic near $k=0$ (unless it's gapless, in which case it's $\propto|\vec k|$). It's just the first term of the Taylor expansion.

Comment: Also, for free non-relativistic electrons we have $E=p^2/2m$, so parabolic is in some sense the "ordinary case".

Comment: @Ruslan - well, anywhere near a minimum or maximum, so the conduction band minimum in Si, not at $k=0$ is also parabolic close enough to the minimum.

Comment: @Ruslan There are gapless dispersion relations for excitations (such as magnons) that have $\omega\propto k^{n}$ for higher powers $n>1$.